# Drag and drop between treeview in uwp

Tags: drag-and-drop, uwp, treeview

I want to drap items from one treeview to another treeview.
I want to use this control TreeView from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tree-view. Whenever i drag control from one treeview to another treeview it throws exception. How to use this control as drag and drop item between treeviews.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging and dropping items between TreeView is not supported in the reference implementation.

> The sample supports:

> - N-level nesting

- Expanding/collapsing of nodes
- Dragging and dropping of nodes **within** the TreeView
- Built-in accessibility

For more information, please see [Hierarchical layout with TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tree-view).

If you need this feature, you may try to implement your own tree view.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you suggest another Treeview control which has Drag and drop feature between treeviews, or can you help with the customization of this control https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tree-view.

Comment: @UrjaPatel I also don't know any other Treeviews support drag and drop between them. Can't help you. :(